# setTimeout never running, with or without clearTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout, cleartimeout

I have the following two functions:

```js
window.onbeforeunload = null;
// this part is never executing
this.timeout = setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("redirecting");
    location.href="/dashboard";
}, 10000);
try { 
    // here I also call the other function
    await this.recorder.stop(); 
} 
catch (err) { 
    console.log(err); 
    clearTimeout(this.timeout);
}
```

And the second one that is called from `this.recorder.stop();`.

```js
console.log("sending mail");
var self = this;
// console.log(blob instanceof Blob);
var file = new File([blob], "recording");
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("recording", file);
formData.append("format", (this.isIOS ? "mp4" : "webm"));
formData.append("routine_id", this.routine_id);
axios.post('/room/send/recording', formData)
    .then(function (response) {
        if(response.data.result) {
            console.log("email has been sent")
        } else {
            console.log("failed to send email")
        }
    })
    .catch(({response}) => {
        console.log("an error occured during email call")
        console.error(response);
    })
    .finally(function() {
        clearTimeout(self.timeout);
        console.log("timeout cleared");
    });
```

But the redirect inside the setTimeout is never executing...
The console.log also does not run.

```js
this.timeout = setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("redirecting");
    location.href="/dashboard";
}, 10000);
```

The `console.log` looks like this (no "redirecting" output)

```
sending mail
email has been sent
timeout cleared
```

Any clues as to why?

Comment: Like did you cleared the timeout (Essentially cancelled it), and you do expect it to run at the same time ? From code you provided it looks like that

Comment: Possibly due to your `setTimeOut()` It redirects after 10 seconds so it first finishes the code, outputs the console.log and then redirects. The `console.log` is fired but the redirect is fired right after. Try to comment the redirect and see if its logged then

Comment: Why are u using this.timeout? Maybe it works when you leave that part away

Comment: @SergeS Thanks, it seems I had misunderstood what cleartimeout does, I thought i just "cleared the time" and executed the function... I actually read the docs more than once before, but I still got it wrong somehow.

Comment: @Jbadminton I was using ```this.timeout()``` so the timeout would be accessible to both functions, since I could not pass it via ```recorder.stop()```, and even without the console.log I did not get redirected.

Comment: This means your `setTimeout` isnt called. you could try to put the code inside the try - catch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @SergeS , I had misunderstood how `clearTimeout()` works entirely.
After clearTimeout, the function is not called anymore, therefore instead of

```
clearTimeout(self.timeout);
```

I also needed to call the function again. Since the function was only a single redirection something like this was fine

```
clearTimeout(self.timeout);
location.href="/dashboard";
```